# Indexing Docuemnts in Lucene automatically

Tags: sql-server, wcf, lucene, lucene.net

I'm building a search engine for my website using Lucene. I want to index any new item that is added to my sql server database. Any ideas about the best way to do that ?

Note : The addition rate is high so you can say that each 10 minutes we have new documents

My lucene code is part of a WCF Data service but I can host it on a separate normal wcf service if this is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use lucene , you can have a thread in your application that queries the DB every 5,6...10 minutes for new additions since last time , for example `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE index_date > last_search_date` .

Assuming that you havea  field that shows when the record was created, this would solve your problem. Other than that,

I would use `solr` and a `cron` job for indexing, as that would prove to be much less work for you.

Comment: I wonder how I could implement a method that can check the database each 10 minutes in wcf data services / on normal wcf at least?